# Find what has been changed and upload only changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, performance

I'm just looking for ideas/suggestions here; I'm not asking for a full on solution (although if you have one, I'd be happy to look at it)

I'm trying to find a way to only upload changes to text. It's most likely going to be used as a cloud-based application running on jQuery and HTML, with a PHP server running the back-end.

For example, if I have text like

```
asdfghjklasdfghjkl
```

And I change it to

```
asdfghjklXasdfghjkl
```

I don't want to have to upload the whole thing (the text can get pretty big)

For example, something like `8,X` sent to the server could signify:
`add an X to the 8th position`

Or `D8,3` could signify:
`go to position 8 and delete the previous 3 terms`

However, if a single request is corrupted en route to the server, the whole document could be corrupted since the positions would be changed. A simple hash could detect corruption, but then how would one go about recovering from the corruption? The client will have all of the data, but the data is possibly very large, and it is unlikely to be possible to upload.

So thanks for reading through this. Here is a short summary of what needs suggestions

- Change/Modification Detection
- Method to communicate the changes
- Recovery from corruption
- Anything else that needs improvement

Comment: interesting question.. you'll have to deal with concurrency issues to. Perhaps sending keystrokes or storing changes to spit at the server at fixed time intervals with a revision number to check against. One problem is that if the text is (very) large you might also have trouble handling it on the client.

Comment: @Hamish: To address your problem, I will have jQuery get the screen dimensions of the device, and the server will send about enough text to fill 3 times that screen. Then, as the user scrolls, the rest of the text can be streamed over. I like your suggestion on time/revisions. I will be sure to keep that in mind.

Comment: unless *your* screens have some gigantic pixel resolution no one else has, 3 screens full of text aren't that much data to handle. I guess about 50-100kb, where's the problem about sending the whole thing to the server?

Comment: You might like to add "corruption detection" to your list

Comment: Joni, you are misunderstanding me. The text is very long, but I only plan to send the text about 3 screenfuls at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already an accepted form for transmitting this kind of "differences" information.  It's called [Unified Diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).

The [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) provides implementations in Java, JavaScript, C++, C#, Lua and Python.

You should be able to just keep the "original text" and the "modified text" in variables on the client, then generate the diff in javascript (via diff-match-patch), send it to the server, along with a hash, and re-construct it (either using diff-match-patch or the unix "patch" program) on the server.

You might also want to consider including a "version" (or a modified date) when you send the original text to the client in the first place.  Then include the same version (or date) in the "diff request" that the client sends up to the server.  Verify the version on the server prior to applying the diff, so as to be sure that the server's copy of the text has not diverged from the client's copy while the modification was being made.  (of course, in order for this to work, you'll need to update the version number on the server every time the master copy is updated).

Comment: Wow Google has some pretty interesting projects going on, but I wouldn't suspect them to have done what I am trying to do. Unfortunately, I am not on a full-blown computer right now, but I will check that project out as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You have a really interesting approach. But if the text files are really so large that it would need too much time to upload them every time, why do you have the send the whole thing to the client? Does the client really have to receive the whole 5mb text file? Wouldn't it be possible to send him only what he needs?

Anyway, to your question:
The first thing that comes to my mind when hearing "large text files" and modification detection is [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff). For the algorithm, read [here](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DiffAlgorithm). This could be an approach to commit the changes, and it specifies a format for it.  You'd just have to rebuild `diff` (or a part of it) in javascript. This will be not easy, but possible, as I guess. If the algorithm doesn't help you, possibly at least the definition of the diff file format does.

To the corruption issue: You don't have to fear that your date gets corrupted on the way, because the TCP protocol, on which HTTP is based, looks that everything arrives without being corrupted. What you should fear is the connection reset. Might be you can do something like a handshake? When the client sends an update to the server, the server applies the modifications and keeps one old version of the file. To ensure that the client has received the ratification from the server that the modification went fine (that's where the conneciton reset happens), the client sends back another ajax request to the server. If this one doesn't come to the server within sone definied time, the file gets reset on the server side.

Another thing: I don't know if javascript likes it to handle such gigantic files/data...

Comment: I'm only going to send what the user can see on the screen. For example, Google Reader only loads a couple of articles when you open it, but as you scroll through the articles, it loads more. If there is too much data, I can remove it once it leavesthe viewport. Thanks for your suggestion to use diff. I will take a look at it later. Even if I cannot port it to Javascript. I am sure that the algorithm will be useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem that versioning systems (CVS, SVN, Git, Bazaar) already solve very well.

They're all reasonably easy to set up on a server, and you can communicate with them through PHP.

After the setup, you'd get for free: versioning, log, rollback, handling of concurrent changes, proper diff syntax, tagging, branches...

You wouldn't get the 'send just the updates' functionality that you asked for. I'm not sure how important that is to you. Pure texts are really very cheap to send as far as bandwidth is concerned.

Personally, I would probably make a compromise similar to what Wikis do. Break down the whole text into smaller semantically coherent chunks (chapters, or even paragraphs), determine on the client side just which chunks have been edited (without going down to the character level), and send those.

The server could then answer with a diff, generated by your versioning system, which is something they do very efficiently. If you want to allow concurrent changes, you might run into cases where editors have to do manual merges, anyway.

Another general hint might be to look at what Google did with Wave. I have to remain general here, because I haven't really studied it in detail myself, but I seem to remember that there have been a few articles about how they've solved the real-time concurrent editing problem, which seems to be exactly what you'd like to do.

In summary, I believe the problem you're planning to tackle is far from trivial, there are tools that address many of the associated problems already, and I personally would compromise and reformulate the approach in favor of much less workload.